# Does java 8 streams reuse itself when processed again on the same data and task?

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I was trying the code to check the time taken by `stream()` and `parallelStream()` for the same operation.

**Code 1**

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList < String > ();

for (int i = 1; i <= 30000; i++)
list.add("a");
for (int i = 1; i <= 20000; i++)
list.add("b");
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
list.add("c");

//part 1
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Map <String, Long> countListSequence = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken in by stream() " + (end - start) + " millisec data " + countListSequence);

//part 2
long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
Map <String, Long> countListparallel = list.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken by parallelStream() " + (end1 - start1) + " millisec data " + countListparallel);
```

**Output 1**

```
Time taken in by stream() 109 millisec data {a=30000, b=20000, c=10000}
Time taken by parallelStream() 16 millisec data {a=30000, b=20000, c=10000}
```

But if I changed the order first use `parallelStream()` then `stream()` like

**Code 2**

```
//part 1
long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
Map <String, Long> countListparallel = list.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken by parallelStream() " + (end1 - start1) + " millisec data " + countListparallel);

//part 2
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Map <String, Long> countListSequence = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken in by stream() " + (end - start) + " millisec data " + countListSequence);
```

**Output 2**

```
Time taken by parallelStream() 109 millisec data {a=30000, b=20000, c=10000}
Time taken in by stream() 15 millisec data {a=30000, b=20000, c=10000}
```

My question is that why the second part `stream()` in **Code 2**   is taking less time then `parallelStream()` showing different behavior from **Code 1**?

Not only in the case of `stream()` and `parallelStream()` I also tried the same situation with `stream()` and `stream()` .I got the same situation with that also, second stream is taking less than first stream.

**Code 3**

```
//part 1
long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
Map <String, Long> countListparallel = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken by stream() 1 " + (end1 - start1) + " millisec data " + countListparallel);


//part 2    
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Map <String, Long> countListSequence = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken in by stream() " + (end - start) + " millisec data " + countListSequence);
```

**Output 3**

```
Time taken by stream() 1 107 millisec data {a=30000, b=20000, c=10000}
Time taken in by stream() 14 millisec data {a=30000, b=20000, c=10000}
```

Second print showed less time then first.So does `stream` calculated data reuse itself if I would believe that how could it be possible because the object created `countListSequence` and `countListparallel` are different.I am confused here how the second part in each code sample take less time then first part.
Am I miising something about streams here?

Thanks

Comment: That's probably due to the first invocation of lambdas involved: it takes time. Create a proper benchmark with JMH and compare the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not at all surprising because the JIT compiler in the JVM optimizes code that has been run a significant number of times.  As a result, it's perfectly normal for code later in the program to run faster than code earlier in the program.

If you want actual useful data here, write a benchmark with a tool like JMH that accounts for JIT warmup.